# Failed to find data source: com.microsoft.kusto.spark.datasource

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I tried to run the following sample code of reading kusto data from spark notebook. (The sample code is from the link: https://github.com/Azure/azure-kusto-spark/blob/dev/samples/src/main/scala/pyKusto.py)

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession    
pyKusto = SparkSession.builder.appName("kustoPySpark").getOrCreate()    
kustoOptions = {"kustoCluster":"<cluster-name>", "kustoDatabase" : "<database-name>", "kustoTable" : "<table-name>", "kustoAADClientID":"<AAD-app id>" ,"kustoClientAADClientPassword":"<AAD-app key>", "kustoAADAuthorityID":"<AAD authentication authority>"}    
# Read the data from the kusto table in 'lean' mode
kustoDf  = pyKusto.read. \    
            format("com.microsoft.kusto.spark.datasource"). \
            option("kustoCluster", kustoOptions["kustoCluster"]). \
            option("kustoDatabase", kustoOptions["kustoDatabase"]). \
            option("kustoQuery", kustoOptions["kustoTable"]). \
            option("kustoAADClientID", kustoOptions["kustoAADClientID"]). \
            option("kustoClientAADClientPassword", kustoOptions["kustoClientAADClientPassword"]). \
            option("kustoAADAuthorityID", kustoOptions["kustoAADAuthorityID"]). \
            option("readMode", "lean"). \
            load()
```

It throws the following exceptions, ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.microsoft.kusto.spark.datasource.

Anyone knows how to fix these?

```
An error occurred while calling o97.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.microsoft.kusto.spark.datasource. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:639)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:164)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.kusto.spark.datasource.DefaultSource
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(DataSource.scala:622)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(DataSource.scala:622)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23.apply(DataSource.scala:622)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23.apply(DataSource.scala:622)
    at scala.util.Try.orElse(Try.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:622)
    ... 13 more

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 172, in load
    return self._df(self._jreader.load())
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o97.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.microsoft.kusto.spark.datasource. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:639)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:164)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.kusto.spark.datasource.DefaultSource
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(DataSource.scala:622)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(DataSource.scala:622)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23.apply(DataSource.scala:622)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23.apply(DataSource.scala:622)
    at scala.util.Try.orElse(Try.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:622)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: What did you do so that it worked?

Comment: I have found this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54227744/pyspark-2-x-programmatically-adding-maven-jar-coordinates-to-spark and it was the solution for it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow the instructions in [the connector README document](https://github.com/Azure/azure-kusto-spark#Linking) on linking Spark Kusto connector. A .jar package of the connector, together with the Kusto Java client data and ingest packages on which it depends, are available [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-kusto-spark/releases).